# Hom-spaces of Segal spaces versus their realization in $\mathbf{Cat}$

Tags: higher-category-theory, infinity-categories

Consider the $\infty$-category of simplicial spaces $s\mathcal{S} = \mathbf{P}(\Delta)$. The
inclusion $\Delta \to \mathbf{Cat}$ induces a left adjoint
$i_! : s\mathcal{S} \to \mathbf{Cat}$. It is well-known that this functor induces an
equivalence between $\mathbf{Cat}$ and the subcategory of complete Segal spaces
$\mathbf{CSS} \subseteq s\mathcal{S}$. We have a slightly larger subcategory of $s\mathcal{S}$
spanned by Segal spaces, those for simplicial spaces $W$ for which the canonical map
$W_n \to W_1 \times_{W_0} \dots \times_{W_0} W_1$ is an isomorphism.

My question concerns the behavior of $i_!$ on Segal spaces. Specifically, these notes ([large pdf](https://florianadler.github.io/AlgebraBonn/KTheory.pdf)) claim
that for a Segal space $W$ and two points $x,y \in W_0$, there is a canonical equivalence (I.65.2) between $W(1)_{x,y}$ and $\mathsf{hom}_{i_! W}(x,y)$

Does anyone know of a reference or argument for this fact? It is clear enough for complete Segal spaces, but the notes seem to indicate that this result as used as an intermediate step to establish the equivalence between quasicategories and complete Segal spaces. However, in the cited proofs by Joyal-Tierney and Lurie, I am unable to see how this particular equivalence is used or established.

Bibliography:

- Lecture notes for Algebraic and Hermitian K-Theory -- lectures by Hebestreit and notes by Wagner
- Quasi-categories vs Segal spaces -- Joyal and Tierney
- (∞, 2)-Categories and the Goodwillie Calculus I -- Lurie

Comment: Completing a Segal space is supposed to change the space of objects, but not the hom-spaces. I'm not sure what the reference is for this fact, but another place I might look is Ayala-Francis' [Flagged $\infty$-categories](https://arxiv.org/abs/1702.02681), which analyzes non-complete Segal spaces from another perspective.

Comment: Another reference is Section 14 in Rezk, where Segal completion is discussed in detail: https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~rezk/rezk-ho-models-final-changes.pdf

Comment: Ah, I can see how to derive the result from this, thanks! If either of you wish to post this as an answer I'll gladly accept (otherwise I can write a small CW answer)